# Analyzing logical form clarification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I want to refer to Example 2.3.1 of Velleman's book "[How to prove it](http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf)" . It is asked to analyze the logical form of $\{x_i\; | \; i\in I\} \subseteq A$. Two possible answers are given. The first one is $\forall x(\exists i\in I(x=x_i) \rightarrow x\in A)$, which I understand. The second one is $\forall i\in I(x_i\in A)$. I don't understand how to go from the first to the second. I would appreciate any guide. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two statements are equivalent. To understand why, it is better to have a closer look at the logical form of the two statements.

First, a clarification. A statement of the form $\forall i \!\in\! I \, P(i)$ is just a shorthand for $\forall i (i \in I \to P(i))$. Similarly, a statement of the form $\exists i \!\in\! I \, P(i)$ is just a shorthand for $\exists i (i \in I \land P(i))$.

Keeping in mind this, let us see how to prove that the first statement

$\forall x(\exists i \in I(x=x_i) \to x \in A)$, that is, $\forall x (\exists i (i \in I \land x =x_i) \to x \in A)$),

is equivalent to the second statement

$\forall i \in I (x_i \in A)$, that is, $\forall i (i \in I \to x_i \in A))$,

using general laws of *logical equivalences*.

\begin{align}
&\quad \ \forall x (\exists i (i \in I \land x =x_i) \to x \in A) &
\\
& \equiv \forall x \forall i ((i \in I \land x = x_i) \to x \in A) &&\text{(because $(\exists i P(i)) \to Q \equiv \forall i (P(i) \to Q)$)}
\\
& \equiv \forall x \forall i (i \in I \to (x = x_i \to x \in A)) &&\text{(because $(P \land Q) \to R \equiv P \to (Q \to R)$)}
\\
&\equiv \forall i (i \in I \to \forall x (x = x_i \to x \in A)) &&\text{(because $\forall x(P \to Q(x)) \equiv P \to \forall xQ(x)$)}
\\
&\equiv \forall i (i \in I \to x_i \in A)) &&\text{(because of the laws for $=$)}
\end{align}